# How to determine which library uses $ sign from console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have handled a project which uses multiple JS libraries, including jQuery. Checked

```
 $.fn.jquery
```

and it returns

> Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined

However,

```
 jQuery.fn.jquery
```

returns the jquery version, which tells me that something else is using the $ sign. Is there any way to determine if some library uses it and which one from console ?

Comment: Just put `$` in the console and start googling the properties it _does_ have.

Comment: Great, found it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All libraries have their own properties and methods,
The better way to find is, type $ in chrome console, and try to expand till you get expected result.

`jQuery` has `fn` object which has `jquery` property which holds version of `jQuery`.

Lets say there is another library which uses `$`, that might has property version to get version.

The better way to use jQuery is using closure.

Here is Example.

```
(function($){//Here you can use $ or $$ or anything which is allowed to use as variable.

})(jQuery);
```